# how to auto test a C program use files?

Tags: testing

I have a C program and I need to test it using a file containing some test data and output the results automatically. How can I do this? Should I modify the program or should I write another program using C or something else like Python? Which is easier?

Here is my C program:

```
int main()
{
    double wh,sh,salary;
    int num = 0;
    int valid = 1;
    printf("Please input two non-negative numbers as a employee's working hours in one week and salary per hour.\n");
    printf("Notice that the salary per hour can't be greater than 1000\nAlso you can't input more than 10 sets of data\n");
    printf("Input them like this:\n20,34\nthen enter the Enter key\n");
    while(scanf("%lf,%lf",&wh,&sh) == 2 && num < 10)
    {
        if(sh <0 || wh <0)
        {
            printf("Salary per hour or salary per hour can't be negative!\n");
        }
        else if(wh > 168)
        {
            printf("Working hours in one week can't be more than 168!\n");
        }
        else if(sh > 1000)
        {
            printf("Salary can't be greater than 1000!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            num ++;
            if(wh <= 40)
            {
                if(sh <= 1000)
                {
                    salary = wh * sh;
                }
                else if(sh > 1000 )
                {
                    salary = wh * 1000;
                }
            }
            else if(wh > 40 && wh <= 50)
            {
                if(sh*1.5 < 1000)
                {
                    salary = 40*sh + (wh-40)*1.5*sh;
                }
                else if(sh*1.5 > 1000 && sh < 1000)
                {
                    salary = 40*sh + (wh-40)*1000;
                }
                else if(sh > 1000)
                {
                    salary = wh * 1000;
                }
            }
            else if(wh > 50)
            {
                if(sh*3 < 1000)
                {
                    salary = 40*sh + 10*1.5*sh + (wh-50)*3*sh;
                }
                else if(sh*1.5 < 1000 && sh*3 >=1000)
                {
                    salary = 40*sh + 10*1.5*sh + (wh-50)*1000;
                }
                else if(sh*1.5 >= 1000 && sh <= 1000)
                {
                    salary = 40*sh + (wh-40)*1000;
                }
                else if(sh > 1000)
                {
                    salary = wh*1000;
                }
            }
            printf("The total working hours is %lf, and salary per hour is %lf, salary is %lf\n",wh,sh,salary);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For this moment please ignore these literals floating around.

I suppose the file containing test data is like this:

```
1,2
34,34
67,43
...
```

I really have no idea how this test automation works,please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in cmd prompt

enter

c:\>myprog.exe < input.txt > output.txt

put all ur testcases in input.txt

ur output will print in the output.txt file